# Vertex AI Executor gives NoSuchKernel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a simple hello-world ipynb file in a Vertex AI notebook instance that looks like this:

```
print("hello world")
```

When setting up an executor for this as shown below I receive the following error in the executor logs: *jupyter_client.kernelspec.NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named local-python3
error*
[image]

The notebook has the following metadata

```
{
    "kernelspec": {
        "display_name": "Python 3 (Local)",
        "language": "python",
        "name": "local-python3"
    },
    "language_info": {
        "codemirror_mode": {
            "name": "ipython",
            "version": 3
        },
        "file_extension": ".py",
        "mimetype": "text/x-python",
        "name": "python",
        "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
        "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
        "version": "3.7.12"
    }
}
```

What would require to run this notebook successfully? I looked into the possibility of customer containers but that should be to much of a complex solution for such.

Comment: I have replicated your task, on a freshly made notebook. All configurations are in default (region: us-central1) and I was able to execute a simple hello world code on my replication with no error. Is it okay to make a new notebook instance on your workbench instead?

Comment: Succeeded with new instance. New instance only had Python kernel installed while previous one also had "Python 3" installed (from conda, i think). This was not compatible with the executor